# onload in iframes not working, if iframe have non-html document in src (pdf or text)

Tags: javascript, iframe, onload

I have iframe with onload handler:

```
<iframe id="FrameForPrintVersion" src="" border="0" style="height:0; width:0; visibility:hidden;" onload = 'frameOnload()' >
```

It works fine if i use html-pages as the source of the iframe, but not when i set src to any pdf document.
Is it posible to handle when a PDF document was loaded in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the W3C, the iframe tag does not support any event attributes.
Although major browsers support it but can not be relied upon.
If you really want it try this workaround.You can try something like this.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    if($('#FrameForPrintVersion').contents().find('*')!='undefined') {
        alert('your frame loaded');
    }
},200)
```

Comment: @aiiak This answer should be marked as the correct one! Also, I suppose you could use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` as an alternative approach for refreshing an iFrame where the connection is slow or the response data is large.

Answer (score 1):

That's an issue with IE. I'm using following as a solution.

```
function dodisable() {
    var b1=document.getElementById('B1'); 
    b1.value='Please Wait....'; 
    b1.disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("browse").src = "hhhh.pdf"; /*LINK TO YOUR PDF*/
    setTimeout( URLoader_Timeout, 100);
}

function doenable() {
    var b1=document.getElementById('B1'); 
    b1.value='Submit'; 
    b1.disabled=false;
}

function URLoader_Timeout() { 
    if ( document.getElementById("browse").readyState == "complete")
        doenable();
    else
        setTimeout( URLoader_Timeout ,100);
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" name="B1" id="B1" value="Go" onclick="dodisable();" />
<iframe id="browse" onload="return  doenable();" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
```